# MediaPlayer start called in state 0 (Error -38, 0), android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making an Android soundboard app and I've put a lot of MediaPlayer values.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bengalka = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bengalka);
    psiho = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cista_psihologija);
    dane = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.da_ne);
    dejo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dejo_narkomane);
    pod = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dizi_se);
    fejs = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fejslifting);
    foto = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fotomale);
    hungry = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gladan_sam);
    jasna = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jasna_pero);
    jeben = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jeben_vam_mater);
    kae = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kae_ivanisevic);
    fora = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kae_to_fora);
    gledas = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kaj_gledas);
    gledate = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kaj_vi_gledate);
    kinezi = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kineza_crnaca);
    kozo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kozo_nepodojena);
    marino = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.marino);
    mater = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mater_zbrgljavu);
    muha = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muha);
    papir = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nema_papira);
    nered = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nered);
    majku = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ne_spominji_majku);
    uroko = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nisam_se_uroko);
    odfurati = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.odfurati_doktoru);
    pljacka = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pljacka);
    puske = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pusi_ke);
    sava = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sava_sava);
    magazin = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tebe_i_magazin);
    vani = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tog_vani_nema);
    dom = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.za_dom_spremni);
    zrigati = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.zrigati);
```

And I've implemented OnClickListener method..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        bengalka.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        psiho.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        dane.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        dejo.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button5:
        pod.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button6:
        fejs.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button7:
        foto.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button8:
        hungry.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button9:
        jasna.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button10:
        jeben.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button11:
        kae.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button12:
        fora.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button13:
        gledas.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button14:
        gledate.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button15:
        kinezi.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button16:
        kozo.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button17:
        marino.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button18:
        mater.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button19:
        muha.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button20:
        papir.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button21:
        nered.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button22:
        majku.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button23:
        uroko.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button24:
        odfurati.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button25:
        pljacka.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button26:
        puske.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button27:
        sava.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button28:
        magazin.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button29:
        vani.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button30:
        dom.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button31:
        zrigati.start();
        break;
    }
```

Now some of the buttons don't work when I click them and I look into the LogCat and it says:

MediaPlayer | start called in state 0

MediaPlayer | error (-38, 0)

Comment: I'm not streaming an internet radio, I'm making a soundboard app :)

Comment: Try stopping the mediaplayer before you start playing the sound in each case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to start media player, when it is not yet prepared. Try to use OnPreparedListener(), and start the player when it's ready, it should look somewhat like this:

```
yourMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
  player.start();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that some files have encodings that android does not support. try to play those files in a regular player.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) link.